# Is there a way to move the taskbar to another monitor?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, taskbar, display

I am using Microsoft Windows XP Professional SP2 and three monitors. I would like for my taskbar to be moved to the third monitor. How can I get it over there instead of on my primary monitor?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

***Simple Way***

1. If you have the Taskbar locked you’ll need to right-click on it and uncheck the option that says Lock the Taskbar.
2. Now here’s the big one…drag the Taskbar onto the other monitor! You can put it wherever you would like.

***Using Software***

[Smart Taskbar](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/smart_taskbar.asp) can add a taskbar to each monitor

[image]

*Using Keyboard*

1. press either the Windows key or  <kbd>Ctrl-Esc</kbd>  to pop the Start Menu up
2. press  <kbd>Esc</kbd>  to close it. The taskbar now has the focus
3. press <kbd>Alt-Spacebar</kbd> to pop the context menu for the taskbar
4. press <kbd>M</kbd> to trigger the 'move' function
5. use the <kbd>arrow</kbd>  keys to move the cursor to another edge of the monitor(s) or press one of the arrow keys and then move the mouse. The Taskbar is now 'attached' to the end of the cursor, so moving the cursor near one of the monitor edges will snap the Taskbar there

You can also select 'Size' (S) instead of 'Move' to easily resize the Taskbar.

[Source](http://www.realtimesoft.com/multimon/faq.asp)

Comment: source :http://cybernetnews.com/cybernotes-getting-your-taskbar-onto-another-monitor/

Comment: Genius! So simple. I feel like an idiot now, thanks.

Comment: Thanks!  I had trouble clicking/dragging because my bar was full of windows and I could not find a spot that would drag.  I needed to resize it so that there was empty space (others might just close their windows).  Then click and drag worked like a charm.

Comment: It was so obvious.... that I had to come here to figure it out !

Comment: I right clicked the Taskbar and selected "Properties", then selected the "Taskbar" tab. Under "Taskbar location on screen" I selected "left" and hit Apply which freed up space on the bar to drag it over to the other monitor, and then selected "Bottom" and apply once done.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to simply change which monitor you're using as your main display.  per:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2002029?wa=wsignin1.0

- Right click the windows background
- Screen Resolution
- Click the thumbnail of the monitor you'd like the task bar on
- Notice the little "make this my main display" checkbox that appears
- check it.

Comment: This implicitly moves the taskbar to the main display, but it doesn't solve the problem since it was stated that the taskbar must not be on the primary screen.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, choosing your default monitor will move the task bar, but not always. This can happen if you have previously moved the start menu/task bar, or if you use software that manages your multi-display setup, like DisplayFusion. If you select a default monitor and your task bar doesn't move to the new default display, you can move it using the method described by [joe](https://superuser.com/a/62036/675340).